# Why does 7-Zip say VDI files are read-only?

Tags: 7-zip

Why can I not edit the [VDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Device_virtualization) file with 7-Zip? I tried running it as administrator and it still didn't work.

Comment: Is the hypervisor running? What OS? Have you checked to see if the file properties says the file is read only?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)?

Answer (score 3):

When you open a VDI file, 7-Zip first opens the VDI level and then it can open more levels ([MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) or [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)).
You can see all open levels if you press "Info" button.

7-Zip can't change VDI, MBR, FAT, NTFS, or ISO images.
It's a read-only feature. It's difficult to support writing the code to support such complicated formats (it's a wrapper around a wrapper).

More than this... 7-Zip wasn't designed for all of the cool s**t the author added after the fact.  It is designed to compress/create/decompress ZIP and 7-Zip files.